# Tumblr: Best way to display photos with proper dimensions

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I would like my template to have different dimensions for a photo, based on it being a portrait or landscape image.

For example:

```
if (dimensions == landscape)
{LinkOpenTag}
    <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" width="800" height="600" class="photo" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />   
{LinkCloseTag}
else
{LinkOpenTag}
    <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" width="600" height="800" class="photo" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
{LinkCloseTag}
```

Comment: You have extra `"`'s before your `class="photo"` in both lines of code.

Comment: Dont hard code width AND height in the same element. Just define one, if you don't this will stretch an image that is 600 x 600 to 800 x 600 for example.

Comment: For clarification, these dimension you are setting, aren't of the image, but something specific you want to set? And you are always uploading these size images?

Comment: @mikedidthis I upload high resolution files, both landscape and portrait. So in the template I would like to recognize when an image is either one of the two and properly set the width or height.

Comment: @user981916 is there a reason why you are setting the width / height attributes? And why 800 / 600px?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly you can't work out if an image is landscape / portrait from Tumblr theme operators alone. You would need to use javascript to work this out.

However, I question why you would need to know this as both the following would display an image, in its natural size / orientation:

```
{LinkOpenTag}
    <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" class="photo" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
{LinkCloseTag}
```

Or:

```
{LinkOpenTag}
    <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" width="{PhotoWidth-500}" height="{PhotoHeight-500}" class="photo" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />
{LinkCloseTag}
```

Reference: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photo-posts

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering...

I wanted to have the photos in different aspect ratios and sizes. If I set a portrait photo as width=800 it will be much "bigger" than a landscape photo with same width.

I guess I will have to work with the {TagsAsClasses}

Comment: @user981916 ahh, that makes sense. Yes I would use `{TagsAsClasses}` and set the width on the parent element, rather than the image element. Good luck!